# Using node.js, how can I put a character inbetween ever other character space in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

An examle of my goal is as is:

```
let string = "hello"
```

My goal is to get this:

```
h.ello
h.e.llo
h.e.l.lo
h.e.l.l.o
h.el.l.o
h.ell.o
he.l.l.o
he.ll.o
he.llo
h.el.lo
//so on until all possibilities are met
```

I have no clue how to approach this, any help would be great, my goal in the end is to have every possible combination of dots and my word which is "hello"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a fun little challenge.

Here's my solution:

```
const interject = (text, char) => {
  const n = text.length - 1
  return Array.from(Array(2**n))
    .map((v,i) => {
      const binary = i.toString(2).padStart(n, '0').split('')
      return text.split('').map((c,j) => binary[j] === '1' ?  c+char : c).join('')
    })
}

console.log(interject('hello','.'))

// prints:
// [
//   'hello',    'hell.o',
//   'hel.lo',   'hel.l.o',
//   'he.llo',   'he.ll.o',
//   'he.l.lo',  'he.l.l.o',
//   'h.ello',   'h.ell.o',
//   'h.el.lo',  'h.el.l.o',
//   'h.e.llo',  'h.e.ll.o',
//   'h.e.l.lo', 'h.e.l.l.o'
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think generators are well suited for this kind of problem. A distinct advantage of the generator is that the caller can decide what to do with each permutation as it comes out. Another advantage is the is the generator can be paused or cancelled at any time, possibly saving many computations depending on the length of the input string.

```js
function* split(s) {
  yield s
  for (let p = 1; p < s.length; p++)
    for (const q of split(s.slice(p)))
      yield s.slice(0, p) + "." + q
}

const result =
  Array.from(split("hello"))
  
console.log(result)
```

```js
[
  "hello",
  "h.ello",
  "h.e.llo",
  "h.e.l.lo",
  "h.e.l.l.o",
  "h.e.ll.o",
  "h.el.lo",
  "h.el.l.o",
  "h.ell.o",
  "he.llo",
  "he.l.lo",
  "he.l.l.o",
  "he.ll.o",
  "hel.lo",
  "hel.l.o",
  "hell.o"
]
```

If you want the `.` to be customisable, don't bother making it an additional parameter. Remember the strength of the generator is that the caller decides what to do with each result. Instead of returning a flat string, the generator can yield an array, allowing the caller to write any rich expression -

```js
function* split(s) {
  yield [s]
  for (let p = 1; p < s.length; p++)
    for (const q of split(s.slice(p)))
      yield [ s.slice(0, p), ...q ]
}

for (const p of split("hello"))
  console.log(`${p.length} pieces joined ${p.join("-")}`)
```

```js
1 pieces joined hello
2 pieces joined h-ello
3 pieces joined h-e-llo
4 pieces joined h-e-l-lo
5 pieces joined h-e-l-l-o
4 pieces joined h-e-ll-o
3 pieces joined h-el-lo
4 pieces joined h-el-l-o
3 pieces joined h-ell-o
2 pieces joined he-llo
3 pieces joined he-l-lo
4 pieces joined he-l-l-o
3 pieces joined he-ll-o
2 pieces joined hel-lo
3 pieces joined hel-l-o
2 pieces joined hell-o
```